# JS - creating new worker causes 404

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, worker, es6-modules

I'm using [Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to create new worker, it's as simple as:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('src/worker.js');
```

Unfortunately I'm using webpack to build my project and linking to `src/worker.js` returns 404.

How can I use it to create my Worker?

```
import hardWorker from './src/hardWorker.js';
var myWorker = new Worker(HOW TO PUT HARDWORKER HERE?);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the *worker-loader* plugin for webpack, which can be found here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader

This registers scripts loaded through it as a Web worker, and bundles all of your workers in the main bundle that webpack creates. Using it in your app is as simple as this:

```
import MyWorker from 'worker-loader!./Worker.js';
const worker = new MyWorker();
```

Or you can add loader configuration parameters to your webpack.config so all files matching a specific pattern are loaded and registered as workers. The worker-loader has an example of this.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the worker API expects a URL to load the work script from and webpack tries to bundle everything into a single file, meaning the `src/worker.js` file isn't where it needs to be when the browser tries to load it.

There are a couple options.

- You could manually copy the `worker.js` file to wherever the build is trying to load the file from.
- You could set up webpack to copy the file to the right location using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).
- Depending on how complicated your worker is, you could just put the code in a string and create an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) so the browser doesn't have to load anything from the server at all. This is an approach I've used in the past and have written a helper library for to Workers a little easier to use.

Hope that helps!